# Shebang pointing to script (also having shebang) is effectively ignored

Tags: macos, bash, shell

Consider following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

print "Hello! I've got %r as input." % sys.stdin.read()
```

This is `chmod +x`ed script in `/usr/local/bin/my_interpreter`. And this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/my_interpreter

This is intended to be passed "as is" to python script.
```

Is `chmod +x`ed script that tries to make use of it. If I `echo something | /usr/local/bin/my_interpreter`, it works fine, but once I try to execute script above, it fails with

```
/Users/modchan/test_interpreter/foo.bar: line 3: This: command not found
```

Seems that `foo.bar` is silently redirected to bash instead of my script. What am I doing wrong? How to make this work?

Comment: Compare to http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20895

Comment: @moodywoody, imho questions are not the same, but the one you linked is quite informative.

Comment: I didn't want to say that the question is a duplicate - just that the other thread is informative.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looks like Mac OS X requires interpreter to be binary, not another script. To make it work, change the second script's interpreter to

```
#!/usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/my_interpreter
```

But you've got a second problem here: the contents of the second script will **not** go to `stdin` of its interpreter, but the script pathname will be passed as command line argument, i.e.

```
/usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/my_interpreter /Users/modchan/test_interpreter/foo.bar
```

You shall read the file by name `sys.argv[1]` rather than from `sys.stdin`.

Comment: Thanks, before your answer I already tried using `/usr/bin/env my_interpreter`, but didn't knew filename goes to argv instead of stdin.

Answer (score 6):

This depends on the program loader of the operating system you're running, which I take to be OS X from your tags. Many UNIX-like operating systems require the shebang interpreter to be a compiled executable binary, not another script with another shebang.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Linux has supported this since 2.6.27.9, but the author of this article suggests that there probably aren't any Berkeley-derived Unixen (which would probably include OS X) that do:

http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#interpreter-script

One way to accomplish what you want would be something like this:

```
$!/bin/sh
exec /usr/local/bin/my_interpreter <<EOM

... content to be executed ...
EOM
```

Another way would be something like this:

```
$!/usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/my_interpreter
... content to be executed ...
```