# When writing a haskell script, get syntax error near unexpected token

Tags: bash, shell, haskell, scripting

When I write a simple script and pass it to runhaskell, it works fine, but not when I add a shebang and try executing it directly. The script is this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/runhaskell

import Data.List (intercalate)

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ intercalate " " $ map show [1..10]
```

If I try `$ runhaskell count.hs` bash prints `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` as expected, but if I try `./count.hs` I get the following error:

```
./count.hs: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./count.hs: line 3: `import Data.List (intercalate)'
```

Is this error originating in bash or runhaskell? And how do I fix it?

Comment: Is that the correct path to `runhaskell`? Because that does look like a shell error. Is runhaskell itself a script with a `shebang`? What system/OS is this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env runhaskell
...
```

Note: this is a feature/issue with OSX where shebang interpreters are required to be binaries. See [Shebang pointing to script (also having shebang) is effectively ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988125/shebang-pointing-to-script-also-having-shebang-is-effectively-ignored) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But why? I did `which runhaskell` to get the path, and running `/usr/local/bin/runhaskell count.hs` in bash worked fine. How come it didn't work in the shebang?

Comment: Not sure, but your code works fine on both my Linux systems (Debian with GHC 7.4 & Arch with GHC 7.8).

Comment: @RamithJayatilleka I'm willing to bet it has something to do with `runhaskell` being a shell script that calls `ghc` with some arguments.

Comment: Added info on OSX behavior.