# What shebang to use for Python scripts run under a pyenv virtualenv

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyenv

When a Python script is supposed to be run from a `pyenv` `virtualenv`, what is the correct [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) for the file?

As an example test case, the default Python on my system (OS X) does not have `pandas` installed. The pyenv [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) `venv_name` does. I tried getting the path of the Python executable from the virtualenv.

```
pyenv activate venv_name
which python
```

Output:

```
/Users/username/.pyenv/shims/python
```

So I made my example `script.py`:

```python
#!/Users/username/.pyenv/shims/python
import pandas as pd
print 'success'
```

But when I tried running the script (from within 'venv_name'), I got an error:

```
./script.py
```

Output:

```
./script.py: line 2: import: command not found
./script.py: line 3: print: command not found
```

Although running that path directly on the command line (from within 'venv_name') works fine:

```
/Users/username/.pyenv/shims/python script.py
```

Output:

```
success
```

And:

```bash
python script.py # Also works
```

Output:

```
success
```

What is the proper shebang for this? Ideally, I want something generic so that it will point at the Python of whatever my current venv is.

Comment: I use this a lot and it works fine. One example of my shebang that works fine: `#!/home/dslima90/.virtualenvs/production_enviroment/bin/python`, maybe check your path? Aren't you missing bin?

Comment: But if you wanto to point to your current enviroment, what is wrong with `#! python` ?

Comment: @DSLima90 The last example shows that the path works fine in running the script directly, so I don't think that's it. I just tried `#! python` and that gives the error `-bash: ./script.py: python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Comment: sorry i have an alias for my python interpreter inside my devel folder, that's why mine works (on development)... anyway `#!/usr/bin/env python` should do it for you... You can try on the command line before. See if it is calling the right interpreter.

Comment: @DSLima90 Oh yeah that worked. I didn't know about that alternative to using the actual path of the executable. Thanks

Comment: @DSLima90 But curious, do you know why using the path wouldn't work?

Comment: I really don't. Maybe something to do with your OS? Anyway I will make my comment an answer so it can also help others!

Comment: You could check with `od -c script.py` if the `#!` really are the first two characters.

Comment: @VPfB I ran the command, and `#!` are indeed the first 2 chars: `0000000    #   !   /   U   s`

Comment: @xgord One possible cause is thus ruled out. Also this might be worth checking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988125/shebang-pointing-to-script-also-having-shebang-is-effectively-ignored  Is the `.../shims/python` another script?

Comment: @VPfB whoah yes, you're right. It turns out it is just a bash script that calls `... exec $pyenv_python` at the end. That file is created by `pyenv` and I just assumed it make a copy or link of a python executable, but that it is not the case. mystery solved!

Answer (score 174, accepted):

I don't really know why calling the interpreter with the full path wouldn't work for you. I use it all the time. But if you want to use the Python interpreter that is in your environment, you should do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

That way you search your environment for the Python interpreter to use.

Comment: Confirmed that it still works in Apr. 2018 with Python 3.6.4, Thanks!

Comment: Thanks to python's "virtual shebangs" feature, this even works on Windows.

Comment: Unfortunately this method now conflicts with Debian Python Package policy, which has deprecated this method in favour of an explicit `/usr/bin/python3` shebang. Can pyenv handle this properly?

Comment: @davidA seems like that would be great as an SO question on its own, for folks looking for a good solution for code intended as debian pkgs. But that particular issue doesn't matter for the use case from my original question, since it's just a user script and still works with current versions of python. (Also the original question was back from the bygone era when python 2 was still a thing, but not sure if that matters in the meta of things)

Comment: I'm coding on Windows for cross platform.  On Linux, I got an error with env command: /usr/bin/env: ‘python\r’: No such file or directory -- so I had to change to newline representation in my python file on Windows and it worked.

Answer (score 21):

If you need to use more shell than you can put in the `#!` shebang line, you can start the file with a simple shell script which launches Python on the same file.

```
#!/bin/bash
"exec" "pyenv" "exec" "python" "$0" "$@"
# the rest of your Python script can be written below
```

Because of the quoting, Python doesn't execute the first line, and instead joins the strings together for the module docstring... which effectively ignores it.

You can see more [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Multiline_shebang#Python).

Comment: @ephemient - this is awesome - I've elaborated a bit more on your suggestion below; hope that is ok

Comment: That's a cool hack, nice work! It does have some downsides: you've set the docstring of the Python module, which you may not want, and your editor may treat the file as a Bash script, using invalid syntax highlighting.

Comment: This will work, but be aware that PID of started and actual process will be different. This may cause some weird issues, for example if you will use such script as systemd service, notifications will not work there.

Answer (score 18):

As you expected, you should be able to use the full path to the virtual environment's Python executable in the shebang to choose/control the environment the script runs in regardless of the environment of the controlling script.

In the comments on your question, VPfB & you find that the `/Users/username/.pyenv/shims/python` is a shell script that does an `exec $pyenv_python`.  You should be able to  `echo $pyenv_python` to determine the real python and use that as your shebang.

See also: *https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209646/how-to-activate-virtualenv-when-a-python-script-starts*

Try `pyenv virtualenvs` to find a list of virtual environment directories.

And then you might find a using shebang something like this:

```
#!/Users/username/.pyenv/python/versions/venv_name/bin/python
import pandas as pd
print 'success'
```

... will enable the script to work using the chosen virtual environment in other (virtual or not) environments:

```
(venv_name) $ ./script.py
success

(venv_name) $ pyenv activate non_pandas_venv

(non_pandas_venv) $ ./script.py
success

(non_pandas_venv) $ . deactivate

$ ./script.py
success
```

The trick is that if you call out the virtual environment's Python binary specifically, the Python interpreter looks around that binary's path location for the supporting files and ends up using the surrounding virtual environment. (See per *[How does virtualenv work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427709/how-does-virtualenv-work*.))

Comment: Knowing how to find the actual path of the virtualenv's python is handy, although this solution is missing the piece that the other 2 answers handle: i.e. being able to execute the script from any currently active virtualenv. It looks like with this method, you'd need to know ahead of time which virtualenv it's going to be executed with and could only execute it via that one virtualenv.

Comment: I found this question in trying to run a script dependent on the packages within a particular virtual environment while being in a different environment.  In particular, I did the development at the command line, but I need to run the script from a cron job.  By calling out the virtual environment's python directly in the shebang, I don't need to first setup a matching virtual environment shell and then call that environment's default python.  It doesn't need to activate any virtualenv at all in the parent process.

Comment: Ah, I now see in your question that you wanted the generic shebang, and not a generically successful execution of a particular virtualenv-dependent script.

Answer (score 5):

To expand this to an answer, yes, in 99% of the cases if you have a Python executable in your environment, you can just use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

However, for a custom `venv` on Linux following the same syntax did not work for me since the `venv` created a link to the Python interpreter which the `venv` was created from, so I had to do the following:

```
#!/path/to/the/venv/bin/python
```

Essentially, however, you are able to call the Python interpreter in your terminal. This is what you would put after `#!`.

Comment: If you're using a git - and people clone it in all kinds of places, then the `/path` changes... it might work for you - but not for others

Answer (score 2):

If you want just a single script with a simple selection of your pyenv virtualenv, you may use a Bash script with your source as a [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Python) as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
PYENV_VERSION=<your_pyenv_virtualenv_name> python - $@ <<EOF
import sys
print(sys.argv)
exit
EOF
```

I did some additional testing. The following works too:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S PYENV_VERSION=<virtual_env_name> python
```

Comment: The one-line works well for running scripts; cleaner than using the full path to the python interpreter, which will change with user.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly answering the question, but this suggestion by ephiement I think is a much better way to do what you want. I've elaborated a bit and added some more of an explanation as to how this works and how you can dynamically select the Python executable to use:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Choose the Python executable we need. Explanation:
# a) '''\' translates to \ in shell, and starts a python multi-line string
# b) "" strings are treated as string concatenation by Python; the shell ignores them
# c) "true" command ignores its arguments
# c) exit before the ending ''' so the shell reads no further
# d) reset set docstrings to ignore the multiline comment code
#
"true" '''\'
PREFERRED_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
ALTERNATIVE_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
FALLBACK_PYTHON=python3

if [ -x $PREFERRED_PYTHON ]; then
    echo Using preferred python $ALTERNATIVE_PYTHON
    exec $PREFERRED_PYTHON "$0" "$@"
elif [ -x $ALTERNATIVE_PYTHON ]; then
    echo Using alternative python $ALTERNATIVE_PYTHON
    exec $ALTERNATIVE_PYTHON "$0" "$@"
else
    echo Using fallback python $FALLBACK_PYTHON
    exec python3 "$0" "$@"
fi
exit 127
'''

__doc__ = """What this file does"""
print(__doc__)
import platform
print(platform.python_version())
```

Comment: Appreciate the comments altho it's still hard to follow. Additional comments explaining the actual control flow could help. (1) starts running bash, obviously, which (2) executes python via exec, and (3) importantly the exec actually executes the original script itself via `$0`

Answer (score -4):

Maybe you need to check the file privileges:

```
sudo chmod +x script.py
```

Comment: The comments below the question explain why it wasn't working. But my examples also showed that the execute bit had to have been set, as the output of `./script.py` was ***not*** `permission denied`, which would have been the case had the execute bit not been set.