# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-search-api

Once I am trying to use google search api it's showing me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maor Ben Lulu\Desktop\Maor\Python\google\google_Bot.py", line 1, in <module>
    from google import google
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
```

My code :

```
from google import google
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def google_scrape(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
#    print(soup.prettify())
    return soup.prettify()
### Rest of the code
```

I did:

```
pip install google
```

But still doesn't work.

Comment: I would like to advice you: if you are going to use google data, you have to use their API .. I tried everything before and nothing works or it works but they block your IP after small time, even if you use these informal packages

Comment: do you have two python versions installed? and are you sure you did "pip install" using an Administrative CMD window?

Comment: What do you get when you run `pip list`?

Comment: How many versions of python have you got? Are oyu sure you did pip install on the right version?

To check if you have the google module, you can run this command

help('modules')

To see all availaible modules.

Comment: @G.Brown google                   2.0.1
google-api-python-client 1.7.4
google-auth              1.5.1
google-auth-httplib2     0.0.3
google-cloud             0.34.0
google-search            1.0.2

Comment: Did pip install the libraries for the right interpretor? The best way to know is to run `print(help('modules'))` in your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError after successful pip installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680081/importerror-after-successful-pip-installation)

Answer (score 9):

This will solve you issue
**But you have to do `import google` not `from google import google`**

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

Answer (score 2):

Install below mentioned package

```
pip install google-cloud
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was a virtual env and shebang: I used absolute path shebang on Debian 12, like `#!/usr/bin/python3`, and it ignored active virtualenv.
`#!/usr/bin/env python` worked, because it uses python from virtualenv, not systemwide.

See [What shebang to use for Python scripts run under a pyenv virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44076804/what-shebang-to-use-for-python-scripts-run-under-a-pyenv-virtualenv)

Answer (score -1):

```
pip install google-cloud-bigquery
```