# How to solve the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google' error?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-api-python-client, python-venv

**THE STEPS I TOOK**

I wish to use Google Cloud Video Intelligence API. Thus, I followed the steps in the section "before we begin" of this Google tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/annotate-video-command-line#quickstart-detect-labels-gcloud. Then I went further in the install process by following these steps: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install-sdk. Thereafter, I followed the steps indicated in this tutorial to setup my Python environment: https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/setup. All went without any issue up until then.

**WORKING DIRECTORY**

I created a directory specifically for this use. Here is its path:
`/Users/romanemeissonnier/Documents/video_intelligence_api`
and here are its contents:

```
.DS_Store
env
key_master_test.json
google-cloud-sdk
master_test_file.py
test_video
```

within *env* directory we have:

```
bin
include
lib
pyvenv.cfg
quickstart.py
```

within *google-cloud-sdk* directory there is:

```
LICENSE             completion.zsh.inc  path.bash.inc
README          data            path.fish.inc
RELEASE_NOTES       deb         path.zsh.inc
VERSION         install.bat     platform
bin         install.sh      properties
completion.bash.inc lib         rpm
```

and within the *test_video* directory is the video (.mp4 file) I will use to test the videointelligence API.

**HOW I GOT THE ERROR**

In order to check if my python virtual environment could access the google module, I used Visual Studio Code and wrote the following:

`from google.cloud import videointelligence`

Which output the following message:

```
No module named 'google'
  File "/Users/romanemeissonnier/Documents/video_intelligence_api/env/master_test_file.py", line 2, in <module>
    from google.cloud import videointelligence
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
```

Comment: Have you tried running `pip install google`?

Comment: @Ahmouse I already did!

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52038874/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-google) you may need to install the `google-api-python-client` Python package

Comment: I already did that as well 