# How to get my script to use my virtual environment rather than my system?

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv, shebang

Using Windows, I cannot get my python script to use my virtual environment when executing in a text editor (Atom).

I know how to use the command line to get my script to use my virtual environment (by activating my virtual environment and running the script) but I want to be able to work in the text editor.

I tried to include the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python` to indicate to my script to use the virtual environment (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44077346/10239494)), but Windows might not actually support shebangs (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7574585/10239494) and [here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/using-shebangs-with-python-3-5-on-windows/30332)). I attempted to directly state the path of my virtual environment but it wasn't clear how to do that (I tried variations of `#!"C:\Users\...\my_project\venv\Scripts\python.exe"`)

Note that my file structure is a folder (*my_project*) containing two folders, *venv* (my virtual environment) and *my_code* (which contains *my_script.py*).

The following script prints paths from my virtual environment when executed from the command line but paths from my system when executed from the text editor. Additionally, I have installed sklearn globally but not in my virtual environment, and sklearn fails to import when executed from the command line (as desired) but imports when executed from the text editor (not desired).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
print(sys.path)

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
```

How can I get my script to recognize the virtual environment I want to use?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a virtual environment, and then activate it in order for the script to use the virtual environment. To do it on atom, follow [this guide](https://atom.io/packages/virtualenv)

Following the quote below should work perfectly from command line. (Once activated, `cd /path/to/script` and then `python myscript.py`)

Quote from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

> To create a virtual environment, decide upon a directory where you want to place it, and run the venv module as a script with the directory path:
>
> `python3 -m venv tutorial-env`
>
> Once you’ve created a virtual environment, you may activate it.
>
> On Windows, run:
>
> `tutorial-env\Scripts\activate.bat`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I already had the command line route working, but don't know how to get the file to just run on its own when executed with a text editor. I took a look at the guide you linked but I don't see how I can use it to make my script recognize the virtual environment in its directory.

Comment: Well it is a n addon for atom if I understand it. You install it and then you can choose the environment for the script to use.