# Python3 shebang line not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix, solaris

I'm having the below issue running a Python script in a Solaris environment.

It appears I have done something incorrect on the shebang line, but I can't tell if this is a Python 3 issue or a command line issue.

But I suspect it's related to the shebang line somehow since when I explicitly run the Python interpreter on the command line there is no problem.

The path `/opt/python3.3.2/bin/python3.3` is the location where my sysadmin chose to put Python, I don't know of this location is problematic somehow on Solaris.

```
$ uname -a
SunOS ... 5.10 Generic_150401-49 i86pc i386 i86pc Solaris

$ cat test.py
#!/opt/python3.3.2/bin/python3.3
import sys
print("hi")


$ ./test.py
./test.py: line 2: import: command not found
./test.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `"hi"'
./test.py: line 3: `print("hi")'

$ /opt/python3.3.2/bin/python3.3 test.py
hi
```

**EDIT:** I can confirm the line endings in test.py are Unix

**EDIT 2:** `od` output

```
$ od -c -N 30 test.py
0000000   #   !   /   o   p   t   /   p   y   t   h   o   n   3   .   3
0000020   .   2   /   b   i   n   /   p   y   t   h   o   n   3
0000036
```

**EDIT 3:** shell is bash

```
$ echo $0
/bin/bash
```

Comment: I am not sure if you are in the same situation i am but I just had this problem.  I was working in notepad++ on windows and then using winscp to put code on a unix machine. For me the solution was to go into notepad++ and do edit -> eol conversion -> unix (lf) and that fixed my issue.

Comment: I've confirmed the line endings are unix

Comment: Another usual suspect is Unicode BOM (byte order mark). Check the first bytes e.g. with  `od -c -N 30 test.py`

Comment: I put the `od` output in the question

Comment: What shell is that? Bash?

Comment: Yes, the shell is bash

Comment: @Mike what do you have when you do a `which python3.3`?

Comment: `$ which python3.3`
no python3.3 in ...

Comment: I don't have it in my `PATH`, but I don't see how that would matter since I'm using the absolute location

Comment: @Mike if you run that `/opt/python3.3.2/bin/python3.3 -c "print('toto')"`, it works?

Comment: Yes, as shown in the question by explicitly calling the Python interpreter using the absolute path, it works as expected

Comment: @Mike indeed... weird

Comment: There is a known limitation for Mac OS X, that it cannot run a script this way, only a true binary executable. Don't know if Solaris might be affected and if this is such case anyway. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988125/shebang-pointing-to-script-also-having-shebang-is-effectively-ignored

Comment: This might be the reason. I just noticed that `python3.3` isn't a binary but a script that calls another Python interpreter.

Comment: @Mike aha..... !

Comment: Why my sysadmin would set it up like this is beyond me

Comment: sysadmin are ... well... sysadmins :)

Comment: Confirmed. When I call the binary that's exec'd in `python3.3` the script works as expected. Thanks @VPfB (you should put that comment in an answer so I can accept it)

Comment: I typically start my scripts with `#!/usr/bin/env python`. You just have to make sure the correct version of Python is the one that gets used when you run `$ which python`

Comment: also keep in mind that some systems have a limit on the length of the path in the `#!` line. I think its ~80 characters on some Linux systems. Might be shorter on Solaris.

Comment: and of course, if might help to run something like `export PATH=/opt/:$PATH` to get that Python in your `$PATH`, and might also have to set your `$PYTHONPATH` as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything important happened it the comments. Let me just summarize it.

After thorough checks that the shebang line itself is correctly written, a similar bug from other system - that I was aware of - was taken into consideration.

As it turned out, Solaris is affected by the same issue as was discussed and solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988125/shebang-pointing-to-script-also-having-shebang-is-effectively-ignored). Summary: *The shebang line requires interpreter to be a binary, not another script*.