# Ansible Playbook fails on a particular server Only

Tags: ssh, ansible, sunos

Below ansible-playbook connectivity works fine for all my servers except dest_svr. Below command fails.

```
ansible-playbook -vvvv /opt/test/Auto/site.yml  -i /opt/test/Auto/hosts.txt -e "source_host=dest_svr execmd=echo source_user=user2"
```

> (0, '', 'OpenSSH_7.7p1 (CentrifyDC build 5.5.1-395) ,
>   OpenSSL 1.0.2o-fips  27 Mar 2018\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data
>   /home/user1/.ssh/config\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data
>   /etc/centrifydc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1:
>   /etc/centrifydc/ssh/ssh_config line 3: Applying options for
>   *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version
>   4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0
>   remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3:
>   mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3:
>   mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 57768\r\ndebug3:
>   mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug1:
>   mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2\r\ndebug3:
>   mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2:
>   Received exit status from master 0\r\nShared connection to dest_svr
>   closed.\r\n') fatal: [dest_svr]: FAILED! => {
>       "changed": false, 
>       "module_stderr": "OpenSSH_7.7p1 (CentrifyDC build 5.5.1-395) , OpenSSL 1.0.2o-fips  27 Mar 2018\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data
>   /home/user1/.ssh/config\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data
>   /etc/centrifydc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1:
>   /etc/centrifydc/ssh/ssh_config line 3: Applying options for
>   *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version
>   4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0
>   remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3:
>   mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3:
>   mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 57768\r\ndebug3:
>   mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug1:
>   mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2\r\ndebug3:
>   mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2:
>   Received exit status from master 2\r\nShared connection to dest_svr
>   closed.\r\n", 
>       "module_stdout": "/home/user2/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1549081965.65-147775141838271/AnsiballZ_setup.py:
>   line 3: _ANSIBALLZ_WRAPPER: command not
>   found\r\n/home/user2/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1549081965.65-147775141838271/AnsiballZ_setup.py:
>   line 4: syntax error near unexpected token
>   `('\r\n/home/user2/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1549081965.65-147775141838271/AnsiballZ_setup.py:
>   line 4:`def _ansiballz_main():'\r\n", 
>       "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", 
>       "rc": 2 }
>           to retry, use: --limit @/opt/test/Auto/site.retry
>
> PLAY RECAP
>   ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************** dest_svr   : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1

Source Ansible Server details:

```
[user1@source_svr: Auto]$ uname -a
Linux source_svr 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 4 20:48:51 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[user1@source_svr: Auto]$ ansible --version
ansible 2.7.1
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/user1/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Sep 12 2018, 05:31:16) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]
```

Ansible Host file details:

```
cat /opt/test/Auto/hosts.txt
[dest_svr]
dest_svr ansible_ssh_common_args="-t -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ControlPersist=30m" ansible_shell_executable=/bin/bash ansible_shell_type=sh ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=false ansible_python_interpreter= ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/opt/test/ssh_key/id_rsa USER_RUN=user2
```

And now the Destination Server details:

```
user2@dest_svr:~$ uname -a
SunOS dest_svr 5.11 11.3 sun4v sparc sun4v
user2@dest_svr:~$ python --version                                                                                                                                                                                    
Python 2.7.14
```

Note: I wish to make changes only to my playbook and do not wish to change anything in ansible.cfg as other playbooks should not be affected.

Comment: Damn, I just now spotted `dest_svr  ansible_python_interpreter= ansible_...` in your inventory file, so you can disregard my answer and either take out that line, or change that line to be the path to your python; also **why would you put that in your inventory?!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As best I can tell it's caused by this:

```
line 3: _ANSIBALLZ_WRAPPER: command not found
```

which is [this line](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.7.4/lib/ansible/executor/module_common.py#L73), but a little digging seems to imply that SunOS shebang lines do not tolerate pointing to an executable that is, itself, also a shebang: [Python3 shebang line not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45444823/python3-shebang-line-not-working-as-expected)

The fix, as best I can tell, would be to set `-e ansible_python_interpreter=/the/path/to/the/real/python` or I've seen [some folks try](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/6345#issuecomment-181999529) `-e 'ansible_python_interpreter="/bin/env python"'` (I modified the path to `env` since [apparently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620) SunOS doesn't have `env` in `/usr/bin/env` but I don't have a SunOS instance to test that theory, so *caveat emptor*)

Comment: On Solaris, `ls -Al /bin/sh` returns `/bin/sh -> amd64/ksh93`. So your default shell is not Bash on Solaris. Oracle also distributes antique software and then charges for a modern version of the software.

Comment: Well, in this specific case the shebang isn't dealing with shell, it's the python interpreter (that's why you get `_ANSIBALLZ_WRAPPER` command not found, because it's trying to run _python_ as if it was _shell_), but from what I'm hearing, I guess `ls -Al /usr/bin/python` will also be a symlink, which is why I said to point it to the actual `python`, or to the `env` binary to side-step the entire discussion)

Comment: or, as I also said, don't do something **patently ridiculous** like set `ansible_python_interpreter` to a blank value in your inventory file

Comment: Thumbs up for using the phrase "patently ridiculous" in a comment!